# Need help with this proof of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am trying to follow a proof of this result (i.e. for $f,g$ in an inner product space, $|\langle f,g\rangle|\le \|f\|\cdot\|g\|$) in the text "Theory of Linear Operators in Hilbert Space" by Akhiezer and Glazman. The part I am having trouble with is (paraphrased for brevity),

"We find that for any real $\lambda$, $0\le \lambda^2\langle g,g\rangle + 2\lambda|\langle f,g\rangle| + \langle f,f\rangle$, which implies that $|\langle f,g\rangle|^2 \leqslant \langle f,f\rangle\cdot\langle g,g\rangle$."

I am assuming there is a clever choice of $\lambda$ which yields the desired result but I am just not seeing it.

Comment: It is a polynomial in the variable $\lambda$, at the inequality you have says it has at most one real root.

Comment: An experience when dealing with this stuff is to "minimize" the right hand side by finding its stationary point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Think of $\lambda^2\langle g,g\rangle + 2\lambda|\langle f,g\rangle| + \langle f,f\rangle$ as a quadratic polynomial in $\lambda$ and try to solve it.

Comment: Oh, I think I see it now. The discriminant is $4|\langle f,g\rangle|^2 - 4\langle g,g\rangle\langle f,f\rangle$. Since the polynomial is nonnegative, it can have at most one real root, so the discriminant can't be positive. Hence $4|\langle f,g\rangle|^2 - 4\langle f,f\rangle\langle g,g\rangle \leqslant 0$, from which the result follows. Very clever, but I wish the authors had made it a bit more clear.